# How can I convert this URL in snowflake to text?

Tags: utf-8, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I receive raw data from URL like this:

```
/%20%20%CF%84%CE%B5%CE%BB%CE%B5%CE%B8%CE%BF%CE%BD%CE%BF%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%CF%80%CF%81%CE%BF%CF%8A
```

or

```
/%20Urologisk%20dr%C3%A6nage
```

or even a normal text like: `example/text`

How can I convert this in snowflake?

Answer (score 1):

If the URL encoded with UTF8 (looks like this is your case), then you can drop the '%' from the string using `REPLACE` function and then decode it using `HEX_DECODE_STRING`. Try this:

```
set url = '%20%20%CF%84%CE%B5%CE%BB%CE%B5%CE%B8%CE%BF%CE%BD%CE%BF%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%CF%80%CF%81%CE%BF%CF%8A';

select hex_decode_string(replace($url, '%', '')) as URL;
```

Output:
[image: example]

Comment: Yes this works fort this case.

Comment: but what if my field is = ' /%20address/ ' ? in this case this did not work

Answer (score -2):

There is no function out of box for this as it is a URL encoded string. But you can create your own function for example in Python to do this, like below example:

```
create or replace function url_decode(url string)
returns varchar
language python
runtime_version = '3.8'
handler = 'url_parse'
comment='convert a url encoded string to string'
as 
$$
def url_parse(url):
    l = len(url)
    data = bytearray()
    i = 0
    while i < l:
        if url[i] != '%':
            d = ord(url[i])
            i += 1
        
        else:
            d = int(url[i+1:i+3], 16)
            i += 3     
        data.append(d)
    return data.decode('utf8')
$$;
```

When I call it:

```
select url_decode('%20%20%CF%84%CE%B5%CE%BB%CE%B5%CE%B8%CE%BF%CE%BD%CE%BF%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%CF%80%CF%81%CE%BF%CF%8A');
```

I get back:

[image]